# Odd margin on my divs, How do I solve this?

Tags: css, xhtml, compatibility

Here is the code i'm working on it's not a page it's a treasure hunt for what might be re-used in a page, I ran into this problem last week or so and I'm asking myself what the heck is this margin for a while here

Let's picture that I can't use the `float:left;` tag for a reason, when I use `display:inline-block;` a weird margin apears on the elements (say divs) how do I fix it?

Problem is on FF3, and IE8 never tested in other browsers but if it dos not work on these what will it work on?

**Original Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Why does that happen</title>
<style type="text/css">

* {padding:0px; margin:0 auto;
vertical-class:baseline;
text-class:left;}

body {padding:0px; margin:0 auto;}

div{margin: 0 auto;}

div div{margin: 0;}

.body {background:#CCC; width:900px; }

.red {background:#F00;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

.blue {background:#03F;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

.green {background:#090;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

.light-blue {background:#39F;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

.light-green {background:#9FC;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

.heavy-red {background:#C00;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="body">


    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="light-blue"></div>
    <div class="light-green"></div>
    <div class="heavy-red"></div>





</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Solved: solution is eliminate the spacing in the markup:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Why does that happen</title>
<style type="text/css">

* {padding:0px; margin:0 auto;
vertical-class:baseline;
text-class:left;}

body {padding:0px; margin:0 auto;}

div{margin: 0 auto;}

div div{margin: 0;}

.body {background:#CCC; width:900px; }

.red {background:#F00;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

.blue {background:#03F;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

.green {background:#090;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

.light-blue {background:#39F;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

.light-green {background:#9FC;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

.heavy-red {background:#C00;
height:300px; width:300px;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:0px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="body">


    <div class="red"></div><div class="blue"></div><div class="green"></div><div class="light-blue"></div><div class="light-green"></div><div class="heavy-red"></div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: P.S. 2004 called, it wants it's xhtml back (xml is dead (on the web))

Comment: yeah like RSS don't need XML or flash apps or CMSs... are you crazy?

Comment: RSS doesn't need XML. It just uses it as a transport because that's what was popular at the time. In fact it's a great example of XML fail because people don't embed xhtml in RSS with namespaces, they do so as CDATA. Fail. xhtml2 isn't going to ship, do yourself a favor and start using HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by spaces in the markup between the divs. If you don't want to float them (why not I wonder), you have a couple of options.

1. Remove the spaces so that the markup is all on the same line.
2. If you don't ever want any text to appear in these divs then you can do this

   div{font-size:0;}

Comment: How in god's name did you find that out? just took away the spacing in the tesxt and just like magic it works, on every browser, I really can seem to make any sense of it because I think space in the markup should not change the output but as it turns out it does!

Comment: Bitter experience. Pressing ctrl + A (select all) can show up problems like this.

Comment: well all I can say it's thanks man, that will help alot my project :D

Comment: I'll ctrl+A every thing after that one! :D

Comment: You can also remove these errant text nodes with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is causing a margin on the left and right of *every* element (that is not `display:inline`):

```
* { margin:0 auto; }
```

You probably want this as your "reset" rule.

```
* { margin:0; }
```

You can then apply `margin:0 auto` to things that you want centered.

Comment: Use a css reset instead of resetting padding and margins with *

Comment: just a comment. When you use margin 0 you do not need to add the px notation, just 0 as margin:0 auto;

Comment: That just will take the content from the center and sit it on the left side of the browser

Comment: what do you mean with css reset, is it not a css reset already?

Comment: If you want the content centred but to remove the padding as budgie suggests, then try div{margin: 0 auto;} div div{margin: 0;}

Answer (score 0):

in all your inner div classes use `margin-left: 0px`

```
.red {background:#F00;
height:300px; width:300px; margin-left: 0px; display: inline-block;
}

.blue {background:#03F;
height:300px; width:300px;margin-left: 0px; display: inline-block;
}

.green {background:#090;
height:300px; width:300px;margin-left: 0px; display: inline-block;
}

.light-blue {background:#39F;
height:300px; width:300px;margin-left: 0px; display: inline-block;
}

.light-green {background:#9FC;
height:300px; width:300px;margin-left: 0px; display: inline-block;
}

.heavy-red {background:#C00;
height:300px; width:300px;margin-left: 0px; display: inline-block;
}
```

I have posted the final html at http://jsbin.com/uwavi3

I had to remove display: inline-block to get it to work on jsbin while on running it locally from a file I didn't have to. I think jsbin uses some sort of reset css.

**Edit2** for float: left kinda layout

Sorry for misunderstanding the question.
Increasing the width of the parent div and using spans instead of div(for colored blocks like red, blue etc.) Works for IE8 and FF3.6. Check here http://jsbin.com/uwavi3/3

Comment: It does not work in fact it doesn't change the end result a bit

Comment: Or indeed the slightly shorter div div{margin-left:0;}

Comment: @Evilalan: It doesn't work for you? It does for me on IE8 and FF3.6. Check the link in edit

Comment: nop, even tested div div {margin:0;} as well, and... The same thing at least of Firefox, how in god's name do this happen?

Comment: @Gaurav Saxena not it just show the same thing, testing on FF also

Comment: @Evilalan: May be its the version. Can you check on IE and Chrome and also can you confirm the version.

Comment: In regards to the Edit: The whole point is to have them all in the same "row" and without margin like they were floatng left

Comment: I'm using IE8 on Windows 7, Firefox 3.6.11 and for webkit I'm using Safari 5.0.1 (7355.17.3)

Comment: @Evilalan: I think I might have got it right now... They are arranged all in a row

Comment: Gaurav Saxena Reposted the code with the answer, and it's unbelievable, it's about spacing the markup itself, just odd as hell check out the new version on the question and if you'd like test yourself, it's the same code without spacing on the divs

Answer (score 0):

I common practice in order your sites to be more cross browser compatible is to use a css reset file. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Comment: Tested with Eric's reset and it's still showing margin where it should not, I'm really curious now

Comment: Local files only, if you know a place where I can upload it right the way that would be nice... Can't use my server tho